# Solr-8.9.0 fuzzy search on name field

Tags: solr, java-11

Enviornment - solr-8.9.0,jdk-11.0.12
To execute fuzzy search over column "name" of .csv file in apache solr i am executing following select query-

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'J Neesham~'&wt=json
```

But in output i am getting following results -
Name - J Cockbain

I have done fuzzy searrch for name:J Neesham, but got result-J Cockbain...These two names are entirely different(Only J is similar) but getting the results in ouptput.
How can i prevent such type of results in outpt, What i have to change in select query?

As suggested , I have changed my tokenizer class to KeywordTokenizerFactory  from StandardTokenizerFactory (default tokenizer class for field-type-'text_general')
Now my managed-schema looks like as follows

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

.....

```
<field name="DOB" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Fathers_name" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="Mobile_number" type="plong" multiValued="false" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Now when i pass 'J Neesham' in fuzzy search, it is not givinng document containing 'J Neesham' in output, Although there are 2 document containing value as 'J Neesham' in solr loaded data. and 1 document containing value as 'J Neeshm'. I want all these 3 documents in output.

Comment: what is the field type applied for name field? try by applying string as field type or combination of keywordtokeniser with lowercase filter factory

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti ...Thankx for reply! I didn't set the field-type, i just loaded the .csv file. In managed-schema, the field-type is 'text_general'. I understand that it is automatically set by solr. How keywordtokeniser
will be configured? Can u direct me to link.

Comment: go to the schema file as apply the fieldtype to your field. create a custom fields type

Comment: Kindly reply!..

Comment: Hello, there is a difference between these two searches: name:"J Neesham"~ and name:J~ AND name: Neesham~. The first is called Proximity Search (https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/the-standard-query-parser.html#proximity-searches) and the second might be what you need.